# REST API call to 3rd party on page load with Axios

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a webpage that I want to populate with data for a user on page load.  I know I can do it once using the `axios.get()` on the specific page I want it to run on.

But what I would like to do is loop through a static list of values and make an API call for each value and then pass that to the user when they visit the page.

I tried doing this in middleware but I am getting an error that my `friend_list` is not defined and I am a bit stumped as to where I am going wrong.

This is my JS file in the middleware

```
    import axios from 'axios'
export default function () {    
    friends_list = [
        { tag: 'friend1' },
        { tag: 'friend11' },
        { tag: 'friend16' },
        { tag: 'friend9' }
    ]    
    friends_list.forEach(i => {
        axios.get('https://some.api/friend/'+i.tags+'/profile')
            .then(res => {
                stats = res.data['d']
                console.log(stats)
                return {
                    game_stats: [
                        {EKIA: stats['a']},
                        {Deaths: stats['b']},
                        {HeadShots: stats['c']},
                        {Wins: stats['d']},
                        {Suicides: stats['e']},
                        {EKIAdRatio: stats['f']},
                        {KillHC: stats['g']}
                    ]
                 }                
            });
    })

};
```

I am able to make this call on my stats.vue page but I am not able to loop through a list on the stats.vue page.

Here is a JSFiddle of my error http://jsfiddle.net/cL9a1pdb/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER:**
There were a couple of errors here that needed to be resolved the first being what was outlined below regarding having the forEach be constructed as `this.friends_list.forEach....`

The 2nd being how I was passing the data nuxt was failing with the error that an object was not defined because it wasnt being populated with data

Working Code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data(){    
    friends_list = [
        { tag: 'friend1' },
        { tag: 'friend11' },
        { tag: 'friend16' },
        { tag: 'friend9' }
    ],
    game_stats: {}
  },
  created(){    
    this.friends_list.forEach(i => {
        axios.get('https://some.api/friend/'+i.tags+'/profile')
            .then(res => {
                return {
                    this.game_stats[res.data['d']['username'] = {
                        {EKIA: res.data['d']['a']},
                        {Deaths: res.data['d']['b']},
                        {HeadShots: res.data['d']['c']},
                        {Wins: res.data['d']['d']},
                        {Suicides: res.data['d']['e']},
                        {EKIAdRatio: res.data['d']['f']},
                        {KillHC: res.data['d']['g']}
                    }
                 }                
            });
    })
};
```

Comment: Can you create a test codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: is there a codepen that supports nuxt? i can not seem to find anything except for just a simple vue template

Comment: How are you importing and using this `friend_list`?

Comment: its statically defined in the middleware like above

Comment: That's how you define the friend list, we need to know how you are currently importing it in a component.

Comment: Just added a JS fiddle that also has my error.  The way I am importing it into a component is just `middleware: ['friend_data']` in the `export default {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is your JSFiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/k0x59p8c/3/) . Basically you forgot a `this` when calling `friends_list`, and some 's' here and there .

About your loop on your axios call, it works, but both your JSFiddle and your example here seem to have the same problem : the way you store the result. It looks like you are ovewriting the value of the variable each time you get a response from your API. In your JSFiddle :

```
.then(response => {
  this.lists = response.data
})
```

This will overwrite `this.lists` each time you get an answer from one of your API call.
Try storing it like this :

```
// "friendId" is a unique identifier for the friend,
// it should be unique to each loop iteration
// for example you can use an id, a gamer tag, or an email 
// linked to the friend's profile

.then(response => {
  this.lists['friendId'] = response.data 
})
```

This way, you will keep the data from all of you axios calls if you are getting different friend's profiles.

**Side note :** `this.lists` as to be an object and not an array to use the `friendId`. You can still use `v-for` on objects in Vue. If you want to keep `this.lists` as an array, you can use :

```
.then(response => {
  this.lists.push(response.data)
})
```

This way you will keep all the data from all API calls, but you won't be able to tell which response belongs to which friend unless some kind of ID is included in the response data itself.

Comment: I appreciate you explaining this but even when correcting all the typos that JSFiddle still does not work it still shows `ReferenceError: friends_lists is not defined`

Is there an example of how to a for loop with this?

Comment: i'm sorry i added the wrong JSFiddle link. I updated my answer, please look at the new JSFiddle I posted (same link as before :"here is your JSFiddle working"). Wait a bit as data is a bit long to load from API :)

Comment: Thanks so the issue is that I needed `this.friends_list.forEach(i => `

Comment: added working code above thanks for the note on the friendId

Comment: With pleasure. Beware, `list` has to be an object and not an array to use the 'friendId'. You can still use `v-for` in Vue to loop through an object. If you want to keep`list` as an array you can use `list.push(response)`, you will keep all the data from all API calls, but you will not know which response belongs to which "friend"

Answer (score 0):

Its because you define friend_list in data. So its undefined in your methods and hooks. You should reference it via this.
Also you have in data friends_list**s** while in method you missed last s and only have friends_list

Comment: so do I need to just do `this.forEach`? then how do I pass it to the method? do I have to define it on the page?

Comment: @FPcond please read some basic js and vue tutorial.. http://jsfiddle.net/7wzojv53/ here you fiddle error fixed if u dont understand what i wrote

Comment: I have read the documentation point me to what I am missing if there is something specific.  Also that jsfiddle doesnt work this is not a typo issue look at my code above i am getting that issue with that code.